# Detect lightning strikes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to add some custom mob conversions like those of villagers/witches and pigs/pigmen (but here it is a block that turns into an mob, not a mob to a mob). What I can't seem to figure out about this is how to detect whether that lightning hit the block or not.

Note: I would like to not use fire as an indicator, as someone could light the block on fire (unless fire from lightning has a data tag that I can use to distinguish it from flint and steel).

Comment: You **might** be able to use something along the lines of `/execute @a[type=LightningBolt] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:<blockname>` and have that output to another command block.

Comment: @Mutantoe - Although you can /summon them, I don't think lightningbolt is a selectable entity.

Comment: @colorfusion yes, I tried "/execute @e[type=LightningBolt] say hi" on a 20gHz fill clock but when I summon a bolt there is no message in chat or output in the command block.

Comment: How many individually blocks are you wanting to test for lightning strikes? Is it just a handful, or a more?

Comment: @colorfusion i'd like to target every block of one type (ex. cobblestone). As modDL showed, you can have an invisible creeper where you want and check to see if that creeper is charged or not on a fill clock, then run the commands based on that charged creeper.

Comment: @user3878893 The problem with that is you'd need a creeper for every block of cobblestone in the world. Even if you got a system set up to spawn the creepers at each block of cobblestone (which is in itself very difficult), the lag from having tens of thousands of creepers (plus checking for them being charged) would be insane.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot select LightningBolt in a target selector so we cannot detect all mobs around a lightning bolt. Instead we can detect all mobs that have a lightning bolt around them.

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Selector dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Initiated dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Marker dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Charged dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Change dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Kill dummy
```

Clock:

```
/scoreboard players set <Select Original Mob> Selector 1
/execute @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiated=0] ~ ~ ~ summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:Marker,CustomNameVisible:0,Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,PersistenceRequired:1}
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Creeper] Marker 1 {CustomName:Marker,CustomNameVisible:0,Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,PersistenceRequired:1}
/scoreboard players set @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiated=0] Initiated 1
/execute @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiated=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=Creeper,r=1,c=1,score_Marker_min=1] @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiate=1,r=0,c=1]
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Creeper,score_Marker_min=1] Charged 1 {CustomName:Marker,CustomNameVisible:0,Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,PersistenceRequired:1,powered:1}
/execute @e[type=Creeper,score_Charged_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiate=1,r=1,c=1] Change 1
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Creeper,score_Marker_min=1] Kill 1
/execute @e[type=Creeper,score_Marker_min=1] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiate=1,r=0] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=Creeper,score_Marker_min=1] Kill 0
/tp @e[type=Creeper,score_Marker_min=1,score_Kill_min=1] ~ ~-600 ~
/scoreboard players set @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiate=1] Initiate 0
/execute @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiate=0] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=Creeper,r=1,c=1,score_Marker_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[score_Selector_min=1,score_Initiate=0,r=0,c=1] Initiate 1
<Run command on entities with Change score of 1>
```

1. Original Mobs Selected
2. Creeper summoned on non-Initiated Selected mobs
3. Mark the summoned Creeper
4. Set the non-Initiated mobs to Initiated
5. Tp the Creeper to the corresponding mob
6. Mark Charged Creepers
7. Mark Mobs that are selected, initiated, and have a charged creeper near them
8. Reset kill score for all creepers
9. Set kill score of all creepers that have a valid mob near them to 0
10. Discard the remaining Creepers
11. Reset Initiate score
12. Set Initiate Score of all valid mobs that have a valid creeper near them to 1
13. Run your command on the mobs marked with Change to swap the mobs.

Comment: While this is a great idea on how to detect a mob struck by lightning, it does not detect blocks being struck.

Comment: I indicated that I was looking for a block being struck, but the creeper method seems like it could work. Is there a way to summon an invisible and noai one above all cobblestone in the world?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess your thing could work but I just use this:

```
/execute @e[type=lightning_bolt, r=100] 
/execute @e[type=lightning_bolt:1,charged:false]~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecraft:grass
```